# Key-value map in python

Tags: python

I have two list of same length `l1=[reboot,revision,disk_space]` and `l2=[no,12.15,4300]` I want to make these two list as key-value map. Output should be like this `[reboot:no,revision:12.18,disk_space:4300]`.. I tried Zip it is not working

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dictionary from the output of `zip` (Thanks, Martijn!):

```
print dict(zip(l1, l2))
```

Comment: or simpler yet: `dict(zip(l1, l2))`.

Comment: when i tried this it always gives the output like this r:no,r:12.18,d:4300. It always takes the first letter as key and ignore the rest

Comment: @VarshaAnandani Provide your full, runnable python code, or better still, a working ideone.com link.